# How to Authenticate User using SNOW OAuth REST API using powershell script?

Tags: rest, powershell, servicenow

The below link i have used to authenticate the user into the service now:

`https://<instance>.-now.com/oauth_token?client_id=<client_key>&client_secret=<client_secret>&username=admin&password=admin`

But i can't able to get the results. I have got the output as below:

```
{
   "error_description": "access_denied",
   "error": "server_error"
 }
```

I need to authenticate the user using SNOW REST API in Powershell scripts.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod

Comment: and the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The First part for using OAuth is getting the access token and second part is to utilize it for fetching data from service now instance (I have commented in the code so that you can find each part and edit variables as per your instance):

```
#For getting access token you can use this code:


$username = “admin”

$password = 'Zen123$$'

$ClientID = “62a88515890332007975e610a3216c62”

$ClientSecret = “pass@word1”


$RestEndpoint = ‘https://myinstance.service-now.com/oauth_token.do’

$body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(‘grant_type=password&username=’+$username+’&password=’+$password+’&client_id=’+$ClientID+’&client_secret=’+$ClientSecret)

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RestEndpoint -Body $Body -ContentType ‘application/x-www-form-urlencoded’ -Method Post

$access_token = $result.access_token


#Once you have access token, you can utilize the invoke-restmethod to fetch data from servicenow : 

$URI = ‘https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1’
$headers = @{“authorization” = “Bearer $access_token”}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers
$result
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhijith pk. It works well. And also i Need to get all the incidents by using OAuth Access token and other stuff. Is it possible?

Comment: Now i got the error like

`Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At D:\SNOW-OAuth.ps1:35 char:8
+ $res = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -Headers $headers
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand`

Comment: @suganthan raj From your first comment i understand that it worked at first, so the later error is due to access token changes after some time. Are you running the whole script second time?

Comment: yep. Sorry @Abhijith pk. I understood incorrectly. Now it works fine. Sorry for the misunderstood.